# Problema al copiar un directorio con archivos a otra ubicación

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, filesystem

La finalidad del programa es hacer que en una listado de directorios venga y copie solo los que han sido modificados y estos copiarlos en otra ubicación
[image: Directorio Base]

Lo que esta resaltado en azul es el directorio y archivo que han sido modificados estos se tienen que copiar a otra ubicación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta carpeta se encuentra en otra ubicación y lo que estan en color rojo es el directorio y archivo que se copiaron de **Documentos** y se movio a **Escritorio**

Mi problema surge cuando quiere copiar la carpeta con algun archivo modificado pero solo copia el archivo pero no la carpeta la deja y en ese momento el programa se cancela

Dejo el código del método

```html
public void CargaArchivo_File(ListBox l, List<String> ListaCarpetas, List<String> ListaArchivos, String DirectorioBase, String Destino)
        {
            String Carpeta_nueva;
            String Nuevo_Archivo;
            String Base = DirectorioBase;

            if (Directory.Exists(Destino))
            {
                Directory.Delete(Destino, true);
            }
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Destino);

            foreach (String Carpeta in ListaCarpetas)
            {
               
                if (Carpeta != DirectorioBase)
                {
                    int tamanio = Carpeta.Length - DirectorioBase.Trim().Length - 1;
                    if (tamanio > 0)
                    {
                        Carpeta_nueva = Carpeta.Substring(DirectorioBase.Trim().Length, tamanio);
                        Carpeta_nueva = Destino + Carpeta_nueva;
                        if (Directory.Exists(Carpeta_nueva))
                        {
                            Directory.Delete(DirectorioBase);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Carpeta_nueva);
                            l.Items.Add("Se creo la carpeta: " + Carpeta_nueva);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (String Archivo in ListaArchivos)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(Archivo);
                Carpeta_nueva = Path.GetDirectoryName(Archivo)+"\\";
                if (Carpeta_nueva != DirectorioBase)
                {
                    int tamanio = Carpeta_nueva.Length - Base.Trim().Length;
                    Carpeta_nueva = Carpeta_nueva.Substring(Base.Trim().Length, tamanio);
                }
                else {
                    Carpeta_nueva = "";
                }
                Nuevo_Archivo = Destino + Carpeta_nueva + Path.GetFileName(Archivo);
                File.Copy(Archivo, Nuevo_Archivo, true); //aqui es donde ocurre el error
                l.Items.Add("Se copia el archivo: " + Nuevo_Archivo);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola, haces mención "lo que estan en color rojo,,," pero no veo información en color rojo.

Comment: Qué tal, ya modifique la imagen. Saludos

Comment: Que quiere decir que deja la carpeta? cual de las dos deja?

Comment: Eso hace referencia que el programa omite (no lee) que se creo una carpeta nueva, un ejemplo, esto pasaría si funcionará `C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Prueba\\CarpetaActualizada\\ArchivoActualizado` pero en realidad pasa esto `C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Prueba\\\\ArchivoActualizado` y en ese momento es donde deja de funcionar

Comment: es que Carpeta_nueva quedo vacia porque Carpeta_nueva != DirectorioBase. esta en tu codigo, que es bastante dificil de seguir. considera poner unos comentarios, es mas hay varias partes de tu codigo que no tienen mucho sentido.

Comment: Esta bien seguiré tus consejos y voy a ver si puedo hacer que el código sea más legible. Saludos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Entiendo que tu pregunta es específica de C#, sin embargo la utilería **Robocopy** de Windows te permite sincronizar carpetas de manera fácil y muy eficiente haciendo **copias incrementales** (solo los archivos que se modificaron o agregaron)

La sintaxis básica es:

```html
robocopy carpetaOrigen carpetaDestino /E
```

Si usas el argumento /MIR también borrará los archivos que se borren de la carpeta origen.

Te dejo unos link de referencia y una página con mas ejemplos:

https://donnierock.com/2016/01/06/sincronizar-y-copiar-carpetas-con-robocopy/

[Página de robocopy de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

[Sintaxis de robocopy en SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: Gracias lo probaré.

Comment: ¿Robocopy te sirvió como solución alterna?

Comment: Qué tal, te comento que con el comando Robocopy no funcionó y si no entendí mal ese comando es como un "accesorio" para windows

Comment: A qué te refieres con accesorio?

Comment: Accesorio me refiero como a una funcionalidad de windows por ejemplo: la lupa, narrador, etc

Comment: Qué lástima que no te funcionó, en mi experiencia funciona muy bien para sincronizar carpetas y archivos con cambios, buena suerte.